# A strengthening of Raabe's test: $\sum a_n$ diverges if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq 1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{A}{n^2}$ for $A>0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The usual form of Raabe's test says that if $a_n>0$ and if for large $n$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq 1-\frac{p}{n}$ for $p>1$, then $\sum a_n < \infty$. A proof I've seen of this relies on the ratio comparison test: $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq 1-\frac{p}{n}< \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^p = \frac{(n-1)^p}{n^p}$, which is $\frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}$ for $b_n = 1/n^p$, which converges for $p>1$.

A partial converse says that if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq 1 - \frac{p}{n}$ for $p\leq 1$, then $\sum a_n$ diverges. To proves this we may again use the ratio comparison test, taking $p=1$, then *a fortiori* it holds for $p<1$.

I am trying to prove a strengthening of the converse, which states: if for large $n$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq 1 - \frac{1}{n}-\frac{A}{n^2}$ where $A>0$, then $\sum a_n$ diverges. It seems we'd like to use the ratio comparison test again, but I'm having trouble finding a series to compare it to.

We might write $1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{A}{n^2} = \frac{n^2 - n - A}{n^2}= \frac{n-1}{n} - \frac{A}{n^2}$, but that doesn't seem to be helping. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**We'll show that the series is divergent whatever the value of $A$ is**

Applying the $\log $ function gives:
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log a_n \geq\log\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{A}{n^2}\right)= - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{A}{n^2}+O(  \frac{1}{n^2})=- \frac{1}{n} +O(  \frac{1}{n^2})$$
so by telescoping  we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \log(a_{k+1})-\log a_k=\log(a_{n})-\log a_1\geq -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{k} +O(  \frac{1}{k^2})\right)=-\log n+ S_n$$
where $(S_n)$ is convergent sequence to a limit say $\ell$ and then
$$a_n\geq a_1\frac{e^{S_n}}{n}\sim_\infty a_1\frac{e^{\ell}}{n}$$
and then we conclude.

Comment: Great solution! Thanks. One question: when you write $$-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{k} + O(\frac{1}{k^2})\right) = -\log n + S_n,$$ how are you getting $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}=-\log n$? The two are asymptotic at infinity, right? Is that what you're using here?

Comment: Oh, I see, I think you've just folded Euler's constant $\gamma$ into $S_n$, and therefore into $\ell$

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I did :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks just like a special case of well-known [Gauss criterion](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Gauss_criterion).

Comment: Thank you. I'm searching for a proof of this online now...

Comment: You can find one for example here: http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matngtb/Calculus/MA3110/Chapter%2013%20Special%20Test%20for%20Convergence.pdf. Basically, it uses Raabe's test.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Here's another I found. http://www.dcs.fmph.uniba.sk/bakalarky/obhajene/getfile.php/new.pdf?id=90&fid=228&type=application%2Fpdf#page=18

Comment: @xen : I don't think this is so well known, to be honest after all the analysis I've done during my undergrad I've never seen this criterion before.

Comment: @xen: You link broke. Could you please supply a working one? Thanks.